# how to make a Multi portal Search Module in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke-module

I am working on custom module for Parent to child portal search but i am not getting idea how it can be done. Anybody with a development plan?

Answer (score 0):

What will you be searching for? Supplying that will help us to formulate a more specific plan. More details please =)

Strictly speaking, you should have one Parent Portal while every other site is a Child Portal. So you can essentially disregard the PortalId if your structure is as stated.